# My Android application is crushing if the database is not populated

Tags: android, database

I got some problem with my database in my Android application. Perhaps, my application is working but let me explain you.

Here are just parts of the code from my app.. i don't want to paste the whole it's not needed.

```
private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
   private static final String INSERT = "insert into "
      + TABLE_NAME + "(name,surname) values (?,?)";


public DataHelper(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
      OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
      this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
    }

public long insert(String name, String surname) {
      this.insertStmt.bindString(1, name);
      this.insertStmt.bindString(2, surname);
      return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
   }

@Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + 
          "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, surname TEXT)");
      }
```

So when i try to run my app i get Force close, but when i put manually :

```
dh.insert("test", "ooo");
```

..in the onCreate method in my main activity everything is fine and working.
So, the conclusion is that i must put some value for the first time i run the app so it can work properly. I thought maybe to update that row with the new informations that i insert later through some TextView's from the app but i'm wondering if there is smarter solution than this?

Comment: How about posting the exact exception you're getting in logcat while this happens? We're no forture teller or mind readers, as in 90% of all cases the exception tells what's wrong

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(260): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mk.com.kb.smetka/mk.com.kb.smetka.najava}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there is no error with your insert, at least it's not what crashes your App.

Since you're getting a CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException, it means you have somewhere a select query and try to move or set it before checking if it's has any rows at all.

This usually happens if you move the cursor to a non-existing index, i.e. `cursor.moveToFirst()`  while your cursor is empty or `cursor.move(n)` where `n` is bigger than `cursor.getCount()-1`

Before moving or accessing a cursor you ALWAYS have to check if any rows are returned!

```
Cursor c = db.query(...);
if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0) {
    c.moveToFirst(); // (or c.move(0))

    // Do your cursor operations here!
}
```

Obviously your insert fails for some reason, you can easily check this, with:

```
long insertId = dh.insert("test", "ooo");

if(insertId > 0) {
    // insert was successfull 
} else {
    // insert failed
}
```